# Docker logging to container

Tags: docker

I'm fresh user of `Docker`. The fist problem with which I'm faced is logging into container.

I'm found solutions to execute container bash commands by

```
docker exec -it ID bash
```

But, this is solution only for install/ remove packages. What to use if I want to edit nginx config in docker container ?

One of solutions can be loggin to container via ssh connection, but maybe `Docker` have something own for this ?, I mean easilly access without install `OpenSSH` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How: Docker logging to container

Yes, you can. You can login the running container.

Exist `docker exec` or `docker attach` is not good enough. Looking to start a shell inside a Docker container? The solution is:  [jpetazzo/nsenter](https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter) with two commands: `nsenter` and `docker-enter`.

#### If you are in Linux environment, then run below command:

```
docker run --rm -v /usr/local/bin:/target jpetazzo/nsenter
docker ps
# replace <container_name_or_ID> with real container name or ID.
PID=$(docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} <container_name_or_ID>)
nsenter --target $PID --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid
```

Then you are in that running container, you can run any linux commands now.

I prefer the other command `docker-enter`. Without login the container, you can directly run linux commands in container with `docker-enter` command. Second, I can't memory multiple options of `nsenter` command and no need to find out the container's `PID`.

```
docker-enter 0e8c248982c5 ls /opt
```

#### If you are mac or windows user, run docket with toolbox:

```
docker-machine ssh default
docker run --rm -v /usr/local/bin:/target jpetazzo/nsenter
PID=$(docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} 0e8c248982c5)
sudo nsenter --target $PID --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid
```

#### If you are mac or windows user, run docket with boot2docker:

```
boot2docker ssh
docker run --rm -v /usr/local/bin:/target jpetazzo/nsenter
PID=$(docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} 0e8c248982c5)
sudo nsenter --target $PID --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid
```

Note: The command `docker run --rm -v /usr/local/bin:/target jpetazzo/nsenter` only need run one time.

> How: edit nginx config

For your second question, you can think about `ONBUILD` in Docker.

```
ONBUILD COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

With this solution, you can:

1. edit `nginx.conf` in local, you can use any exist editor .
2. needn't build your image every time after you change nginx configuration.
3. every time, after you change `nginx.conf` file in local, you need stop, remove and re-run the containe, new `nginx.conf` file will be deployed into contrainer when `docker run` command.

You can refer the detail on how to use `ONBUILD` here: [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/)

Comment: What's the problem with docker exec?

Comment: @AdrianMouat, I run `docker exec`, but some time, only got blank windows, and some time logoff directly. With `nsenter`, I didn't have this issue.

Comment: I've had very few problems with docker exec and would recommend against the extra complexity of nsenter unless necessary. I've never seen "blank windows" (I'm not really sure what this means), but it sounds like a bug.

Comment: @AdrianMouat  Nice, maybe you can help to fix this issue: `docker run -d -p 10086:10086 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock tobegit3hub/seagull`, then `docker exec d57eb761985b sh`. can you login the container?

Comment: @AdrianMouat Regarding your book `Using Docker`, if you can publish it as  ebook (such as pdf) and keep updating as what `The docker book` did, I will be first to buy the book. I keep getting the latest version of `the docker book`, that's the most cool book I have.

Comment: Thanks. It's already available as an early release e-book: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920035671.do. I've not looked at your image, but it sounds like you should open a GitHub issue for that.

Answer (score 2):

as you said,

`docker exec -it container_id bash`

and then use your favorite editor to edit any nginx config file. vi or nano is usually installed, but you may need to install emacs or vim, if this is your favorite editor

if you have just a few characters to modify,

`docker exec container_id sed ...`

might do the job. If you want to SSH into your container, you will need to install SSH and deal with the SSH keys, I am not sure this is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You're going about it the wrong way. You should rarely need to log into a container to edit files.

Instead, mount the `nginx.conf` with `-v` from the host. That way you can edit the file with your normal editor. Once you've got the config working the way you want it, you can then build a new image with it baked in.

In general, you have to get into the mindset of containers being ephemeral. You don't patch them; you throw them away and replace them with a fixed version.